# How to add link on navigation bar? html

Tags: css, web, html

so I've just started making my own personal website, however, I'm running into issues with my navigation bar. Basically I want to be able to click on the titles on my navigation bar and then it will direct me to section pertaining to that title on my page. 
To make things more clear. Take for example, this is what I have so far for my navigation bar:

```html
<div class="about"> <a> About &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  </a> </div>
<div class="blog"> <a> Blog  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </a> </div>
<div class="projects"> <a> Projects &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp </a> </div>
```

Now my nav bar should look something along the lines of this:
            About     Blog     Projects
And the rest of my webpage looks likes this

```html
<h1> About me </h1>
<p> Hi im nikki.. </p>

<h2> Blog </h2>
<p> This is my blog.. </p>

<h3> Projects </h3>
<p> First project last year .... </p>
```

Now what I want to be able to do to is to click on About on my navigation bar and make it take me to the About section on my page? How do I do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you used anchor tags before?

Comment: I only know to do that when it comes to linking to another website, but how do I do it within sections of my own webpage?

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code, add the style to your stylesheet.

```
    <style>
    .nav:after {
    content:"";
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    }
    .nav li {
     float: left;
     list-style-type: none;
     }
     </style>
     <ul class="nav">
       <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
       <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
     </ul>
    <div id="about">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
    <div id="blog">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
    <div id="projects">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: Jquery UI Tabs]

Do you need something like this ? 
Then easy way of doing it is , using JQuery-UI Tabs.

To know n learn more about it , just read through the documentation, Its easy comparatively doing it with plain css & JS.

reference Link : https://jqueryui.com/tabs/